# Drupal 8 themeing best practice

Tags: themes, drupal-8

I've installed Drupal 8 - and activated the bootstrap theme. I've placed this in a contrib folder -- is it best practice that I create a custom folder - and start to add over-riding based templates?

I used to develop with drupal 6/7 - and used a themeing tool that could indicate the exact templates to use/make.

Or do I hack the installed bootstrap theme?

Answer (score 0):

Best practice is to create a [subtheme](https://www.ostraining.com/blog/drupal/create-a-drupal-8-bootstrap-subtheme-using-cdn/) and place it in a contrib folder for all overrides.

---

Edit:
There are a number a good [debugging](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/theming/twig/debugging-twig-templates) options for D8 theming.

Comment: Ok - what about any development modules to tweak templates - cause it used to be -page-home.php - or something to start overriding

Comment: Thank you - I've got the subtheme working - how do I start overriding the other templates?

Comment: Did you turn the new theme on in admin/appearance? If you turn on debugging like I mentioned above you'll be able to use the Chrome developer tools and see the recommended templates in the source code. As you create them in your subtheme it'll override the default bootstrap ones. In your subtheme you should have a "templates" folder for the overrides (within you can further organize by layout, blocks, views, nodes, etc).

Comment: where is the debugging option in admin/appearance?

Comment: one of the things I want to do - is adjust the bootstrap subtheme - grid layouts to start tweaking it for mobile

Comment: The debugging that I linked to above is set within code (directions in the link but you'll add a few lines to the sites/default/services.yml file which turns on the debugging). That will give you file name suggestions when viewing a page (including page, node, block, view, field, etc).

Drupal has some good general theming tutorials as well: https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/theming